# NHibernate Convert query to async query

Tags: sql-server, linq, nhibernate

I'm looking at async-ifying some of our existing code. Unfortunately my experience with NHibernate is lacking. Most of the NHibernate stuff has been easy, considering NHibernate 5 has a lot of support for async. I am, however, stuck.

Originally, we do something like this using our Dependency Injection:

```
private readonly IRepository repository;

public MovieRepository(IRepository repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
}

public Movie Get(int id)
{
    return (from movie in repository.Query<Movie>()
        select new Movie
        {
            ID = movie.ID,
            Title = movie.Title,
            Genre = new Genre
            {
                ID = movie.Genre.ID,
                Name = movie.Genre.Name,
            },
            MaleLead = movie.MaleLead,
            FemaleLead = movie.FemaleLead,
        }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //Repository Query method in Repository.cs
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : OurEntity
    {
        session = session.OpenSession();
        return from entity in session.Query<TEntity>() select entity;
    }
```

This works great for our current uses. We write things this way to maintain control over our queries, especially related to more complex objects, ensuring we get back exactly what we need.

I've tried a few things, like making the Query method return a Task< List< TEntity>> and using the ToListAsync() method, however because I am returning it as that kind of list I cannot query on it.

I'm sure I've missed something. If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in this case.

```
public async Task<Movie> Get(int id)
{
    return await (from movie in repository.Query<Movie>()
        select new Movie
        {
            ID = movie.ID,
            Title = movie.Title,
            Genre = new Genre
            {
                ID = movie.Genre.ID,
                Name = movie.Genre.Name,
            },
            MaleLead = movie.MaleLead,
            FemaleLead = movie.FemaleLead,
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: A quick google search tells me that FirstOrDefaultAsync is an Entity Framework IQueryableExtension. This will not work for me.

Comment: No, this isn’t an EF extension.

Comment: @Blankdud, It is not because something exists in EF that it is an EF only thing... If you have tried it in your code and have not found it, maybe are you just missing an `using NHibernate.Linq`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `using` statement to your file

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

Then you can change your method to

```
public async Task<Movie> Get(int id)
{
    return await (from movie in repository.Query<Movie>()
        select new Movie
        {
            ID = movie.ID,
            Title = movie.Title,
            Genre = new Genre
            {
                ID = movie.Genre.ID,
                Name = movie.Genre.Name,
            },
            MaleLead = movie.MaleLead,
            FemaleLead = movie.FemaleLead,
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

NB: This is [only available from NHibernate 5](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/releases/tag/5.0.0)

Addendum:
The code you have in `Repository.cs` can be simplified to something like this:

```
//Repository Query method in Repository.cs
public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : OurEntity
{
    //session = session.OpenSession();  //this is obviously wrong, but it's beside the point
    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    return session.Query<TEntity>();  //the fix
}
```